# UITableViewRows Not Visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple UITableViewController and none of the rows are displaying. The table view header and section headers are all there. I have never encountered this. Thoughts?

```
import UIKit

class DashboardTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countyName: String?
    var sections = ["Quota Over/Short", "Qualified Renewals", "Membership Dues"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if countyName != nil {
            self.title = "\(countyName!) County"
        } else {
            self.title = "County Info"
        }
        
        let headerView = DashboardCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 200))
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 2
        } else {
            return 9
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .label
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .black
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", size: 25)
        cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "-500"
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Previous Year: 1500"
            } else {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Current Year: 1000"
            }
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "Test Dues"
        }
        
        return cell!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: add the background of infoLabel and check

Comment: Debug hierarchy view: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html do you see the cells?.

Comment: Show your cell class... is it a Storyboard Prototype? or purely code? It's odd that you would use `cell.infoLabel?.text` ... if your cell's `infoLabel` is **optional** that code will not do anything if the label was not created correctly.

Comment: @DonMag See my update. I tried using a default tableview cell and am having the same issue.

Comment: Instead of `UITableView.automaticDimension`, return 44 to see.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's code in the Collection View used in the header is what's causing the problem, so no answer to this question can solve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code in a different view caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer the question about Prototype or Code-based cell class, and the code you've shown (in `cellForRowAt`) is not the right way to use table view cells.

Without seeing your custom cell setup, try it like this with a "default" cell:

```
class DashboardTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countyName: String?
    var sections = ["Quota Over/Short", "Qualified Renewals", "Membership Dues"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if countyName != nil {
            self.title = "\(countyName!) County"
        } else {
            self.title = "County Info"
        }
        
        // I don't have your DashboardCollectionView class, so I'm creating
        //  as plain UIView with a blue background
        //let headerView = DashboardCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 200))
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 200))
        headerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        
        // register a default UITableViewCell
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 2
        } else {
            return 9
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }
    
    //override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //  return UITableView.automaticDimension
    //}
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // don't do it like this
        //var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        //if cell == nil {
        //  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        //}
        
        // dequeue a registered cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultCell", for: indexPath)
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .label
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
        }
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", size: 25)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "-500"
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Previous Year: 1500"
            } else {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Current Year: 1000"
            }
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Test Dues"
        }
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

If that works (which it will), then try to use this code to figure out why your custom cell is not working.

Comment: I am no longer using a custom cell. I'm using a default cell. My storyboard does not have any prototypes in it.

Comment: @raginggoat - ok... this code doesn't use a prototype cell. Does it work for you?

Comment: No, it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Then you must have some other code that's changing something. Use a new `UITableViewController` and assign its custom class to `DashboardTableViewController` using the exact code I posted. It will give you that result.

Comment: It looks like it's my DashboardCollectionView tableview header causing the issue. I replaced it with a plain view like yours and my original code worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

From the image it looks like UITableView allocated space for your cells. I would recommend testing the cell by

1. NOT reuse cell just to see if you can get something to show up
   `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)`
2. Set background color to something
   `cell.backgroundColor = .red`

If you see the cell show up then you know at least the tableview is giving you the correct # of cells

Comment: Tried both of these suggestions with no luck. I've also printed the label text for each row to the console and get the correct values.